# How to fix `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` when testing i18next with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a react project and I have included i18next = 15.0.4 and react-i18next = 10.2.0 dependencies. I have created a module for initializing i18next with react-i18next and I'm trying to unit test this code using Jest.

I tried importing my i18n module that initializes i18next and unit testing it using jest.

Here is my module for i18n.ts

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

const config = {
    resources: {
        en: {
            static: {},
        },
    },
    fallbackLng: "en",
    defaultNS: "static",
    ns: "static",
    interpolation: {
        prefix: "[",
        suffix: "]",
    },
};

i18next.use(initReactI18next).init(config);

export default i18next;
```

And I'm trying to call it from my test code like this (i18n.test.ts):

```
import i18n from "./i18n";

describe("i18n", () => {

    it("should work fine", () => {
        const strings = {
            key: "value",
        };
        i18n.addResourceBundle("en", "static", strings, true, true);
    });
});
```

I would expect this test to pass, but instead I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
      at I18n.use (node_modules/i18next/dist/commonjs/i18next.js:257:18)
```

Which basically points out to this code in i18next.js

```
    value: function use(module) {
      if (module.type === 'backend') {
        this.modules.backend = module;
      }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

`const reactI18nextModule = require("react-i18next");`

instead of

`import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";`

read a bit more about require vs import for jest testing here:

[Jest mocking default exports - require vs import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056694/jest-mocking-default-exports-require-vs-import)

hope it helps :)

Comment: how can I export useTranslation with require?

Comment: I don't understand the question ? :) you're asking about es5 module export? ```module.exports = foo;```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you followed this guide:
https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

It says you should use this mock:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  withTranslation: () => Component => {
    Component.defaultProps = { ...Component.defaultProps, t: () => "" };
    return Component;
  },
}));
```

But when you do this, there's no `initReactI18next` which you're trying yo use here:

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
i18next.use(initReactI18next).init(config);
```

The documentation sabotages you :(

What you need is to either remove stubbing or provide the `initReactI18next` key in your stub module.

I've notified the authors here: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next-gitbook/pull/42

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made an update from <=`V9` to >=`V10`. Because `reactI18nextModule` is not anymore available in >=`V10`. Try to use `initReactI18next` instead.

For more details go to https://react.i18next.com/latest/migrating-v9-to-v10

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock `initReactI18next`. Try the following:

```
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => {
  const useMock = [k => k, {}];
  useMock.t = k => k;

  return {
    useTranslation: () => useMock,
    initReactI18next: () => {}
  };
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Failing function:

```
function use(module) {
      if (module.type === 'backend') { // cannot read `type` of `undefined`
```

Conclusion: `module` is `undefined`. It is coming from:

```
i18next.use(initReactI18next)
```

Conclusion: `initReactI18next` is undefined. It is coming from:

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
```

Conclusion: `initReactI18next` is not something exported from `react-i18next`

Comment: `initReactI18next` is exported from "react-i18next"