# React render on I18nextProvider causing React.createElement type is invalid errors

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am importing `I18nextProvider` like this: `import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next"`.

I use it like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={myTranslator.getInstance()}>
        <MyComponent {...props} />
    </I18nextProvider>,
    this.target
);
```

However, on the I18nextProvider component I get an error in jest test when attempting to render, but nothing in regular build or use. Looking at other instances it seems my imports could be the issue but my import seems fine. Is there something I am missing?

---- EDIT ----
Looks like this is a duplicate of: [How to fix `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` when testing i18next with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507684/how-to-fix-typeerror-cannot-read-property-type-of-undefined-when-testing-i1). Where my jest configuration needed to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the default import but here named import is required

```
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my question. The import was named as you suggested. But it still throws errors and only from jest.

Comment: have you added this in your jest conf ??

Comment: In my situation I had it as part of global config, which I removed since it only was needed for 2 components. This fixed the issue from my side.