# Mock jwt-decode in Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

For test purposes I need to mock jwt-decode library. I use it as follows:

```
const decodedToken: { exp: number } = jwt_decode(token);
```

And then in tests tried the following and got errors like below:

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode');
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'exp' of undefined

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => ({
  exp: 123,
}));
```

> TypeError: (0 , _jwtDecode.default) is not a function

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/47056694/7470360 (but I don't think it's a duplicate).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is with the second argument of `jest.mock`. In your example, it is a function that returns an object:

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => ({ ... }))
```

but as the property you are trying to mock is the default export of the module, the argument needs to be a function that returns a function that returns an object:

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ ... }))
```

Comment: I had to do `jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => ({ default: () => ({ ... }) }))`.

Comment: Thanks @zbr It has worked for me nicely.

Comment: How do i return different return values in different specs?  I have tried ```      const jwt = jest.mocked(jwtDecode)
      await jwt.mockImplementationOnce(() => result)``` but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user1801879 see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45006254/7470360. Does that help?

Comment: @AJarofClay i was able to use chatgpt to find an answer and it had worked

Answer (score 1):

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => ({
  jwtDecode: () => 'some-name',
}));
```