# How to mock the jwt-decode in jest

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, jwt

This is the code that i have to mock in testing

```
 import * as jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
 const reg: string = jwtDecode<ITokenDTO>(token)['jti'];
```

and i am going to use this reg as `const result = await thirdpartylib.some_method(getToken(reg));`

and this is what i have written so far `jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({}))` but i am not sure whether its right or wrong,
can someone correct it if it is wrong or give the confirmation if it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be marked as a duplicated. The answer here below has a good explanation, and the proposed solution could be a right one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398466

The solution that worked for be is the following:

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => ({ default: jest.fn(() => ({})) }));

...

      expect(jwtDecode).toBeCalledWith('whatever');
```