# Unable to mock jwt-decode in Jest

Tags: typescript, testing, mocking, ts-jest

For testing purposes I need to mock jwt-decode function but none of the suggestions I've found here helped. The code were jwtDecode is used looks like this

```
 import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
 ...
 const { exp } = jwtDecode(accessToken);
```

And inside the test I need to mock this returned `exp` value. I've tried mocking it as per suggestion found in [Mock jwt-decode in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395349/mock-jwt-decode-in-jest)

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ exp: 123456 }));
const { exp } = jwtDecode('123456');
```

But that returns

> InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified: Cannot read property
> 'replace' of undefined

Answer (score 5):

For those who also run into this issue - found a way to solve it.

Add this line on the top of your file (before test suite definition)

```
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => jest.fn());
```

And the mock the value inside tests f.e. like this:

```
(jwtDecode as jest.Mock).mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ exp: 12345 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @justenau answer, if not using typescript, we can mock the import inside individual tests like so:

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

// do a generic mock at the top of your file:
jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => jest.fn());

// then somewhere inside your test
jwtDecode.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({ exp: 12345 }));

OR

jwtDecode.mockReturnValueOnce(() => ({ exp: 12345 }));
```