# PIXI.js tests with Jest in react SPA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library, pixi.js

I have a react app with animation rendered with PIXI.js and
@inlet/react-pixi.

When running tests with Jest, I get errors:

`Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'stage')]`

`● run Homepage tests › is Homepage rendered`

```
WebGL unsupported in this browser, use "pixi.js-legacy" for fallback canvas2d support.

   5 | describe('run Homepage tests', () => {
   6 |   test('is Homepage rendered', () => {
>  7 |     render(
     |     ^
   8 |       <MockedProvider>
   9 |         <HomePage />
  10 |       </MockedProvider>`
```

How should the pixi.js-legacy be implemented as the fallback for tests?

`"@inlet/react-pixi": "^6.8.0",`
`"pixi.js": "^6.4.2",`
`"jest-canvas-mock": "^2.4.0",`

UPD:

Mocking pixi.js with pixi.js-legacy I got this error:

[image]

However, I tried to import pixi.js-legacy:

`import 'pixi.js-legacy';`

And got the same kind of error:

[image]

It seems that there is some problem with importing 'pixi.js-legacy'.

What could go wrong with it?

Has anybody ever seen an example of Jest or other framework tests that works?

Comment: See: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/8338 , https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues/8337 , https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/tree/dev/bundles/pixi.js-node

Answer (score 1):

If it's really working with the legacy version then you can swap the libraries while testing.

Install `pixi.js-legacy` as a dev dependency.

1. Create `setup-jest.js` in your root directory.
2. Add the content

```js
jest.mock('pixi.js', () => jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));
```

3. Modify your Jest configuration and add the following line

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.js']
```

This will mock your real Pixi library with the legacy one.

##### EDIT

For ES6 imports try

```js
jest.mock('pixi.js', () => {
  return {
    default: jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy')
  };
});
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47056694/jest-mocking-default-exports-require-vs-import)

Comment: good day. I've tried your solution, as I'm using a CRA based react app with ts, in order to avoid ejecting, I added `jest.mock('pixi.js', jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));` to setupTests.ts. Then I got this error: 
TypeError: /Users/.../src/setupTests.ts: The second argument of `jest.mock` must be an inline function.

      2 | import 'jest-canvas-mock';
      3 |
    > 4 | jest.mock('pixi.js', jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));

Comment: After fixed that I got another error: 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

      2 | import 'jest-canvas-mock';
      3 |
    > 4 | jest.mock('pixi.js', () => jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Jest docs haven't helped me at all

Comment: Apparently it needs a callback instead of direct passing. Like `jest.mock('pixi.js', () => jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));` But can you show more details about the other error you are facing?

Comment: This that new error: 
src/App.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

      2 | import 'jest-canvas-mock';
      3 |
    > 4 | jest.mock('pixi.js', () => jest.requireActual('pixi.js-legacy'));
        |                                 ^
      5 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pixi.js-legacy/src/index.ts:13:12)

Comment: Honestly not sure why it's failing but you can verify it by logging in tests to make sure mocked PIXI actually has the properties you are expecting. Maybe you need to export it using `default` key. I'll update the answer and you can try that too

Comment: I've updated the post with my attempts to mock pixi with the legacy, and I also tried to import pixi.js-legacy like `import 'pixi.js-legacy';`, and in this case I got the same error: ` TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')`. Anyway, have you ever seen working test with PIXI?

Comment: Honestly, no. Never tried it

Comment: have you read my comment from week ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394433/pixi-js-tests-with-jest-in-react-spa/73395199?noredirect=1#comment129621462_73394433  . Problem is that you want to run PixiJS (no matter if "legacy" version or not) in node.js environment - when it is intended for use in browsers. Please try this way: https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/tree/dev/bundles/pixi.js-node  or https://github.com/bigtimebuddy/pixi-node-example

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```bash
npm i -D jest-webgl-canvas-mock canvas
```

- jest-webgl-canvas-mock: let node can ues webgl
- canvas: canvas usage

and add import into `./jest.config.json` like down below

```json
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "setupFiles": ["jest-webgl-canvas-mock"]
}
```

it actually help me to fix this problem

[fix-prop-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAfu6.png)

Comment: Where to import jest config json... in the test? And, should I pass this object to Jest during initialization?

Comment: > Where to import jest config json... in the test? 

just create it at root , Jest will auto discovered it

>should I pass this object to Jest during initialization?

is unnecessary